# How to convert a string to list using clisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How can i convert the string `"1 2 3 4 5 6 7"` into the list `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)` elegantly? I am using CLISP.

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to do? "String to list" to me implies going from a string to a list of characters, but your example is reading things separated by whitespace.

Comment: i am a lisp newbie. And i have not find "split" like funtion. Up to now, i can use "parse-integer" to convert "123" to 123.

Comment: With cl-ppcre: `(mapcar #'parse-integer (ppcre:split #\space "1 2 3"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Take a look at [with-input-from-string](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_in_f.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a recursive solution.

```
    ;Turns a string into a stream so it can be read into a list
    (defun string-to-list (str)
        (if (not (streamp str))
           (string-to-list (make-string-input-stream str))
           (if (listen str)
               (cons (read str) (string-to-list str))
               nil)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`parse-integer`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_parse_.htm) in a loop.

For example, using `loop`:

```
(let ((string "1 2 3"))
  (loop :for (integer position) := (multiple-value-list 
                                    (parse-integer string
                                                   :start (or position 0)
                                                   :junk-allowed t))
        :while integer
        :collect integer))
```

⇒ `(1 2 3)`

If you need better control about the splitting, use the `split-sequence` or `cl-ppcre` library.

If you need to parse more general number formats, use the `parse-number` library.

Libraries are available from Quicklisp.

Answer (score 2):

```
(with-input-from-string (s "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" :index i :start 0 :end 13)
              (list (read s) (read s) (read s) (read s) (read s) (read s)))
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
```

it works however i feel it is not so elegant as there are many `read` call .

thanks again!

Comment: `(with-input-from-string (s "1 2 3 4 5 6 7") (loop for x = (read s nil :end) until (eq x :end) collect x))` should work, but note that it will take `"one two three"` to a list of symbols rather than a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work:

```
(setf s "1 2 3 4 5 6 7")
(setf L-temp (coerce s 'list))
```

This makes a list with spaces as elements. Remove spaces:

```
(setf L-final (remove #\Space L-temp))
```

Comment: This produces the list `(#\1 #\2 #\3 #\4 #\5 #\6 #\7)`, i. e. a list of digit characters.  Aside: don't `setf` variables that do not exist.

Comment: I see Svante is correct. I tried again and posted the answer using read-from-string. I'm still beginning to learn Lisp. So, I am curious about not "setf variables that do not exist". Is that a violation of functional style? Or does it make my code more confusing in larger programs?

Comment: No, it is just undefined behaviour.  You are implicitly creating a global variable that may or may not be _special_ (dynamic).  Use `defparameter` or `defvar` to create a new globally special variable, or use `let` (or other constructs introducing a local scope) to create local variables.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation, Svante. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I see that Svante is right. My previous attempt did not work. Here is another attempt. I use concatenate to change the string into a list representation. Then I use read-from-string to convert the string (s-2) into an actual list.

```
(setf s-0 "1 2 3 4 5 6 7")
(setf s-1 (concatenate 'string "(" s ")" ))
(setf s-2 (read-from-string s-1))
```

I roll it into a function like this:

```
(defun from-string-to-list (s)
  (let ((L (read-from-string 
           (concatenate 'string "(" s ")"))))
    L))
```

The only purpose of "let" and "L" is to make the function from-string-to-list return only the list and not return multiple values. read-from-string returns two values: The list and the size of the string, I think.

Answer (score 0):

That would do,

```
(with-input-from-string (s "1 2 3 4 5")
   (let ((r nil))
      (do ((line (read s nil 'eof)
                 (read s nil 'eof)))
          ((eql line 'eof))
          (push line r))
   (reverse r)))
```

Comment: additionally, in the above form, in the first list you can replace a string, here `"1 2 3 4 5"`, with a form like `(read-line stream)`, to read a line from a stream yet not yielding a string but a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [map](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map.htm) function:

```lisp
(map 'list #'identity "1 2 3 4 5 6 7")
```