# How can I read a string in a line in Common Lisp?

Tags: string, common-lisp

```
aaa bbb ccc
```

Fot the above line, I just want to get the sring `"aaa"`, just like `scanf("%s",str)` in C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a string to list using clisp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459501/how-to-convert-a-string-to-list-using-clisp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem gracefully you need a function to extract words. This may work, or you can find some good library:

```
CL-USER> (defun split (str token &aux result (len (length str)))
           (labels ((rec (i)
                      (if (< i len)
                          (let ((p (or (position token str :start i)
                                       len)))
                            (when (/= p i)
                              (push (subseq str i p) result))
                            (rec (1+ p)))
                          (reverse result))))
             (rec 0)))
SPLIT
```

This function traverses given string and copies its parts that don't contain given token. Note how we don't copy entire string on every recursive call, but move 'pointer' `i` to know where to start next search.

Now you can use `nth` to access any word:

```
CL-USER> (nth 0 (split "aaa bbb ccc" #\space))
"aaa"
CL-USER> (nth 1 (split "aaa bbb ccc" #\space))
"bbb"
CL-USER> (nth 2 (split "aaa bbb ccc" #\space))
"ccc"
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, [`scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html) does *tokenization*, i.e., it splits on whitespace. This corresponds to [`read`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) in Common Lisp:

```
(with-input-from-string (s "aaa bbb ccc")
  (list (read s) (read s) (read s)))
==> (AAA BBB CCC)
```

Note that `read` returns [`symbol`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_symbol.htm)s for unquoted strings; if you want [`string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_string.htm)s,  you are looking for something like:

```
(defparameter *my-string* "aaa bbb ccc")
(subseq *my-string* 0 (position #\Space *my-string*))
==> "aaa"
```

Comment: Then what about "bbb"?

Is there a function like scanf("%s",str)?

Or I hava to write it by myself?

Comment: Thanks! But I want original string "aaa" instead of the symbol AAA.

Comment: If the original string is "aAa", function read will make all characters capital.

Comment: Take a look at [`symbol-name`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_2.htm) and [`readtable-case`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rdtabl.htm). However, the symbols will still be interned, so you will need to unintern them to have them garbage-collected.

Comment: While it is possible that someone already wrote a scanf for CL (vsedach/Vacietis seems to have one), I would still write it myself, maybe using flexi-streams library.